# sed filter to substitute '!' for periods and '!!' for periods at the end of lines

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sed, end-of-line

I want to write a sed filter that changes all periods in its input to exclamation marks, unless the period is at the end of a line, in which case the period is replaced with 2 exclamation marks (ie. !!).

So far, this is what I have:

```
sed -e 's/\./\!/g' -e 's/\!\n/\!\!\n/g' input_exp
```

where input_exp is a file that has a few sentences written in it.  The command does not work though.  Is '\n' not the correct end of line character in unix/bash?  Do I need an extra '\' before '\n'?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The main problem with this is that the \n is not replaced with a newline when you put the pattern in single quotes - it's treated as a literal slash and then an n.  If you put the pattern in double quotes, then you also need to escape the ! chars (which you've done unnecessarily here). :)  The answer below which uses a $ instead of a \n is correct.  It's also probably slightly faster to do the checks in the opposite order, as in darioo's answer (since that would just have one substitution per line, as opposed to two).

Comment: Not only that, but the order the original is written will double `!` at the end of a line regardless of whether or not it used to be a `.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e 's_\.$_!!_g' -e 's_\._!_g' input_exp
```

I've used `_` instead of `/` for a slightly higher degree of readibility. You can also use

```
sed -e 's/\.$/!!/g' -e 's/\./!/g' input_exp
```

if you want to, of course. `\n` stands for newline, and is not the same as end of line.

Comment: The pattern should be enclosed in single quotes to prevent variable interpolation and shell escapes.  This actually won't work with double quotes. :)

Comment: @dannysauer: Fixed :-) I've used a Windows version of sed. You don't have fancy *nix shell features in Windows command prompt, so there is rarely a distinction between single and double quotes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$` for 'end of line' inside the regex.

Comment: If you put that pattern in double quotes, you should escape the dollar sign.